# Ansible & AWS secret manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-secrets-manager

I´m looking for a way to get credentials from AWS secret manager from local host and then pass it in a secure way to the client host.
For security reasons, only the instance role assigned to the EC2 running ansible is able to retrieve values from secret manager, for that reason I need to make a delegate_to local host or similar to get the secret and then use it in client host.
Regards.

Tried to use AWS secret manager modulo but I was not able to figure the way to pass the value to client host.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal:

- in Ansible you can create `local_action` task, which will download Secret on the EC2 eligible for obtaining the secret
- make sure to register its output to variable
- query the result variable using json_query filter, for the secret you're looking for, and register the output as another variable
- use the variable in any remote tasks